# What's this style of website called?

Tags: website-design

I've seen several of these 'all on one page' sites recently - with links from the top menu further down the front page, rather than to separate pages - and a dynamic 'wizz down the page' action.

For example: [www.jbmc.co.uk](http://www.jbmc.co.uk/)

I presume these are flavour of the month. What is this style called?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64993/general-name-for-the-website-style-that-appears-in-wide-pages

Comment: Internet breaking gimmick.

Comment: With all that bloody animation, it's called a UX nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate.  And yes I think its pretty horrid as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **one-page responsive website**.

More descriptively, it's a one-page/long-scrolling responsive website with a hero shot, sticky header, and scrolling transitions.

Let's break that down:

- **One page** refers to a site where the principle content narrative appears in sections on a single page rather than on different linked pages (as in a traditional website). This is sometimes also called a long-scrolling layout if the page is very long.
- **Responsive** refers to a site which is designed to accommodate different device (desktop, tablet, mobile) widths, often by using adaptive layouts. The jbrm site renders quite well in both mobile and desktop using the same html content.
- **Hero shot** refers to the large format feature photo/graphic at the top of the page. Often (as with this site) this is a background image.
- **Sticky header** is the header at the top of the page which can change style as you scroll.
- **Scrolling transitions** are the animated effects as you scroll down.

---

Note that this is not really an infinite scrolling site.  Generally infinite scrolling refers to sites where content is loaded dynamically (eg via Ajax) as a user scrolls. For this site, the content is actually loaded once. Scrolling transitions are used to give the impression that the page is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Single Page or One Page sites (or applications). Yes, flavor of the month. A design option.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually called infinite scrolling with a hero shot. It describes it well but  obviously not all sites have "infinite" scrolling.

Comment: I think you're incorrect here. Surely infinite scrolling is where you can scroll infinitely? Such as with Twitter or with blog sites where it keeps loading in the next page as content at the bottom so you never reach the end of the page.

Comment: @Jonw infinite scrolling pages (poorly termed!) can be bounded (eg instagram used to have a cap on photos loaded), but the conventional definition is a long form page where content is loaded dynamically as the user scrolls.

Comment: @JonW -  You're correct in that infinite scrolling originally (and most properly ) refers to sites in which more content is loaded as the user scrolls down. However a lot of people I've met (developers as well as content producers, and business users) use the term infinite scrolling to mean one-very-long-page-where-all-the-content-resides-even-if-additional-information-is-not-loaded-dynamically.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the case with this site. All we're seeing is transitions as the content animates into view. Pretty standard themeforest stuff, but I wouldn't term it Infinite scroll; all the content is already there it's just animating when you reach it.